# Google Apps Script: Referencing the ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, activex

I wish to create an Excel object from within App Script.  The following resource:

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?249479-Javascript-excel-object

shows how to do so using Javascript - I was therefore hopeful that I could use this code within Google Apps Script:

```
function xlTest() {
    var xls = new ActiveXObject ( "Excel.Application" );
    var newBook = xls.Workbooks.Add;
    newBook.Worksheets.Add;
    newBook.Worksheets(1).Activate;
}
```

When I try to run this function I get the error message:

ReferenceError: "ActiveXObject" is not defined

Hopefully I simply need to add a reference to ActiveXObject, if so could somebody please advise how I add a reference to ActiveXObject from Google Apps Script?   Many thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to use VBA objects in Google Apps Script? It doesn't work for the same reason for which Google Sheets and Excel are different apps.

Comment: Could you perhaps share more details about this integration? The runtime environment of Google Sheets is very different from that of Excel, so I'm not sure I understand your specific use case. Would you like to convert a GAS spreadsheet object into Excel workbook object?

Comment: Anton here is a link to the activeXobject creation for javascript. .. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/activexobject-object-javascript  thank you for your interest, I am very grateful

Comment: This question has been tagged as unhelpful, based on the premise to the question being flawed.  I therefore should like to delete the question, but as it has been answered Stack overflow discourages deletion.  Any advice please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with Google Apps Script (or even JavaScript) and should not be tagged as such. You can't simply throw this code into Google Script Editor and expect things to work.

GAS is a JavaScript-based runtime that lives on Google servers, not in your browser. It doesn't have access to BOM (Browser Object Model) Furthermore,  ActiveX is not supported in most browsers, including Microsoft Edge. Of course, VBA methods like Sheets.Add won't work for obvious reasons.

If you log the global object in Script Editor, you'll see all of its properties available to you as a developer. 
[image]

In your browser, the properties of global object will be different:

[image]

Please take the time to go through GAS documentation and understand features & limitations https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: Many thanks Anton.  It looks therefore that I may have to establish communication between the two application artefacts using VBA and the world-of-pain that is oAuth2.  Best regards, Malcolm